# How to disable "smart" quote replacement for Russian in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

How to disable "smart" quotes replacement for Russian? It is disabled in AutoCorrect window but still works:

[image]

Comment: To clarify , you want to keep `<<` and `>>` instead of getting guillemets (`«` and `»`)?

Comment: No, I want to keep "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the settings in the “AutoFormat As You Type” tab. The “AutoFormat” tab only applies to automatic formatting as requested by a command, not to on-the-fly formatting.